# How to Create Dynamic Auto Completer for Particular Column in QTableWidget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget shown below. I have added Auto completer using item delegates for particular column ‘Name’ which does work well.

Given list to autocompleter : ['Mark','Riya','Andrew','Thomas','Kevin','Leena','Julie','Peter','Rob','lily','Rambo']

I want to make this more dynamic. i.e if I type ‘R’. it is giving me values which starts from ‘R’ as shown in snapshot. BUT I also want to get the values which has ‘R/r’ at any position like ‘Andrew’, ‘Peter’.

[image: WorkFlow]

Or the other scenario would be, If I type ‘B’ , I should get ‘Rob’, ‘Rambo’ instead of no suggestions currently.

How can I make this work?

Code Generated by Qt Designer:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1048, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 861, 511))
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.AnyKeyPressed|QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked|QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 4, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ID"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "City"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Occupation"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Newyork"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4796423643344"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Teacher"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Chicago"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "43683284"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nurse"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from demo import Ui_MainWindow

class TableItemCompleter(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent)
        completionlist = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
        autoCompleter = QtWidgets.QCompleter(completionlist,parent)
        autoCompleter.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        editor.setCompleter(autoCompleter)
        return editor

class demo_code(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super(demo_code, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(TableItemCompleter())     

        for rows in range(0,5):
            item = QTableWidgetItem('')
            item.setData(Qt.UserRole,['Mark','Riya','Andrew','Thomas','Kevin','Leena','Julie','Peter','Rob','lily','Rambo'])
            self.tableWidget.setItem(rows, 0, item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = demo_code()    
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very simple, as QCompleter has a few filter mode options. In your case you want `Qt.MatchContains`. Add this line to your `TableItemCompleter` class:

```
autoCompleter.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
```

You can see each type of filter mode [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum) and the `filterMode` method [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop).

Comment: Thanks much. i didn't know about this.